# Не работает update в Laravel resource?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Создал контроллер

```
php artisan make:controller LanguageController --resource --model=Model/Language
```

но при update метод не видит $language

```
public function update(Request $request, Language $language)
```

а так работает

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
```

отправляю данные так

```
updatel(){
                const that = this;
                let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('id', this.edit.id);
                formData.append('name', this.edit.name);
                formData.append('image', this.edit.image);
                formData.append('code', this.edit.code);
                formData.append('locale', this.edit.locale);
                formData.append('sort_order', this.edit.sort_order);
                formData.append('published', this.edit.published);
                formData.append('_method', 'PUT');
                axios.post(this.url.update+this.edit.id, formData)
                    .then((response) => {

                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        toast.fire({
                            icon: 'error',
                            title: error.response.data.errors
                        });
                    });
            },
```

Comment: Попробуйте `public function update(Request $request, Language $id)`, либо в роутах `{id}` заменить на `{language}`

Comment: я лох, вот так надо было public function update(Request $request, Language $localization)